# When trying to run Shell script getting fi unexpected error

Tags: shell

```
if [ -s data_stnd_viol_addr.log ];
  
    if [ ${update_instance} == "BPROD"  ] 
    then
            echo | mailx -s "***** Data Standard Violation - Address *****" -S"from=banner" -a"data_stnd_viol_addr.log" ${BPROD_LIST};
        elif [ ${update_instance} == "B8QA"  ]
        then
            echo | mailx -s "***** Data Standard Violation - Address ***** QA" -S"from=banner" -a"data_stnd_viol_addr.log" ${QADIST_LIST};
    else 
        echo | mailx -s"***** Data Standard Violation - Address ***** DEV" -S"from=banner" -a"data_stnd_viol_addr.log" ${QADIST_LIST};
    fi
fi
```

Comment: Run your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fix what it flags.

Comment: (the _very first_ thing it points out is that your first `if` is missing a `then`).